# Why is xelatex not found on PATH?

Tags: xetex, miktex

I tried to run the command

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf xxx.ipynb
```

and I got the error

> xelatex not found on PATH, if you have not installed xelatex you may need to do so.

Xelatex does not exist in MiKTeX package manager i tried to get the xelatex package and add it or to update MiKTeX packager manager but always it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not seem like a TeX.SX question. Check that `xetex` is installed in MiKTeX. You'd also need to include the location of *tex binaries into the `PATH` variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you've done here: you might have a 'bust' MiKTeX install. Does XeTeX work from the Command Prompt (_e.g._ with `xetex --version`)?